# Are all non-oscillating positive sequences monotonic?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am studying the behaviour of a divergent (to infinity) positive sequence. I wanted to conclude that since it is positive and divergent to infinity, it is monotonic. Can I conclude that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,7,6,8,\ldots$

Comment: This is crystal clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No.  For instance, $a_n = \frac12n + (-1)^n + 1$ is positive and diverging to infinity, but not monotonic.

However, you can always extract a strictly monotonic subsequence, if that would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

No. Another example: $a_n=n^2 $ if $n$ is even and $a_n=n$ if $n$ is odd.